# ActiveMQ Remote Broker

Tags: php, activemq-classic, stomp

I'm an ActiveMq - STOMP PHP- Beginner.

How can I connect to a remote Broker on STOMP, the Producer is in php.
If I connect to the broker on the same machine like this:

```
 $stompCon = new Stomp('tcp://localhost:61613');
 $stompCon->connect();
 $stompCon->send('/queue/notifications.test', $mapMessage);
 $stompCon->disconnect();
```

it connects ok, but when I try on an external server like:

```
 $stompCon = new Stomp('tcp://181.61.50.8:61613',$user,$pass);
 $stompCon->connect();
 $stompCon->send('/queue/notifications.test', $mapMessage);
 $stompCon->disconnect();
```

It doesn't connect. Does someone knows how I can connect to a remote broker on another machine?

Error messsage:

> Internal Server Error
>
> The server encountered an internal error or misconfiguration and was
>   unable to complete your request.
>
> Please contact the server administrator, webmaster and inform them of
>   the time the error occurred, and anything you might have done that may
>   have caused the error.
>
> More information about this error may be available in the server error
>   log.
>
> Additionally, a 500 Internal Server Error error was encountered while
>   trying to use an ErrorDocument to handle the request.
>
> Apache Server at  Port 80

Comment: How do you want to find out what's wrong if you don't know an error message? A lot of things may be wrong. Error message usually says, what's wrong.

Comment: It says: "More information about this error may be available in the server error log." Did you consider checking it? Noone can guess the error. Maybe the remote broker is offline?

Comment: There was a problem with my server provider, where I was sending messages ..Now it works "TCP/UDP connections (outbound and incoming) to non-generic ports are forbidden by default"